# Proof of the matrix of change coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

If i have the reference frames  $R$ and $R '$, and I call $M(R',R)$ the matrix that changes coordinates from  $R'$ to $R$. 
Let's say that $R=\{p,e_1,\dots,e_n\}$, $R'=\{p,e'_1,\dots,e'_n\}$ and $R''=\{p,e''_1,\dots,e''_n\}$ are the reference frames from $A$ I have to prove that $M(R,R')=M(R'',R') \cdot M(R,R'')$

I tried to do it in a long way, putting all the members of the matrix and doing the product but I ended doing a mess.
Does anyone know any easier way to do it?

Sorry if I didn't use the correct way to write the mathematic things, I'll try to do it beter next time.

Comment: You say "I tried to do it in a long way", could you please share your attempt?

Comment: To be honest I ended deleting it but

I know that from $R'$ to $R$ should be something like this:
The coordinates from $E$ of the vector $\vec{OA}$ are $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)_E$ and the ones of $\vec{OO'}$ $(e_1,e_2,e_n)_E$. 
Then we have that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1
x_2
\dots
x_n
\end{bmatrix}
=
  \begin{bmatrix}
e_1
e_2
\dots
e_n
\end{bmatrix}
+P
\begin{bmatrix}
x'_1
x'_2
\dots
x'_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$P$ being the matrix that changes basis.
So I thought that probably $M(R,R')$ was 
$x'=e'+Px$
and i tried to make these equal:
$e'+Px=(e'+Px'') \cdot (e''+Px')$.

Comment: But probably my way of reasoning it is wrong because my knowledge about algebra / geometry is poor. And maybe the matrix of the change of basis is different so it should have a different leter in every case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let be the same point $A$ espressed in different coordinate systems:

$A\; is\;\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}$ $\; and\; is\;\{x'_1,x'_2,...x'_n\}$ $\; and\;is\;\{x''_1,x''_2,...x''_n\}$

The matrix that transforms from $R$ to $R'$ is $M(R,R')$,  and let's note any matrix $M(K, J)$ as "from $K$ to $J$". Example with coordinates in "row":

 $\{x'_1,x'_2,...x'_n\}=\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}·M(R,R')$  $\;\;\;$(1)

So we can also say

 $\{x''_1,x''_2,...x''_n\}=\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}·M(R,R'')$  $\;\;\;$(2)

 $\{x'_1,x'_2,...x'_n\}=\{x''_1,x''_2,...x''_n\}·M(R'',R')$  $\;\;\;$(3)

Replacing (2) in (3) we get:

  $\{x'_1,x'_2,...x'_n\}=\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}·M(R,R'')·M(R'',R')$ $\;\;\;$(4)

Compare (1) and (4) and you get

$M(R,R')=M(R,R'')·M(R'',R')$

Now, if you work with vectors in column, instead of row, you must transpose all equations, and remember "the transpose of a product is the swapped product of transposed":

 $\{x'_1,x'_2,...x'_n\}^T=M(R,R')^T·\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}^T$  $\;\;\;$(5)

and, by rewritting (2)(3) you can arrive to $M(R,R')^T=M(R'',R')^T·M(R,R'')^T$

Notice that if you define $M$ as "row ordered" you use (1). But if the same $M$ notation means "column ordered" then (1) is of type $\;X'=M·X\;$ and the transpose operations are not needed and you can do the prove by simple (2)(3) rewritting in proper order.